# It won't let me use Fill to fill the data

Tags: c#, .net

I don't understand why it gives me the following error message "does not contain a definition for `Fill`" on this line `trackCollection.Fill(data);`

Here's my controller method for your inspection:

```
public static List<DBTrack> GetDBTracks()
{

    SQLDBTrackData sql;

    if (DBTrackData == null)
    {
        List<DBTrack> daa = new List<DBTrack>();
        DBTrack trackCollection = new DBTrack();
        System.Data.DataTable data = new System.Data.DataTable();
        trackCollection.Fill(data);
        DBTrackData = new List<DBTrack>();
        foreach (DataRow p in data.Rows)
        {
            DBTrack top = new DBTrack()
            {
                // TrackID = Convert.ToInt32(p.Field<double>("TrackID")),
                AddedDate = p.Field<DateTime>("DateTimes"),
                TrackName = p.Field<string>("TrackName"),
                ArtistName = p.Field<string>("ArtistName"),
            };

            DBTrackData.Add(top);
         }
    }
    return DBTrackData;
```

}

Any help would be great.. Thanks

Comment: Show `Fill` method in `DBTrack` class

Comment: @Marek Hi, thanks and I'm trying to get the `.Fill` bit to work so that it fill it with the data.

Comment: @Nalaka526 thanks, good point but I already have it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 possibilities.

1. The Class `DBTrack` has no method `Fill()`
2. It has a private `Fill()` method that you should make public.

Comment: thanks for that, #2 was the issue. how stupid of me.. was `private` and changed it to `public`.